# Performance Testing of Thrift API

Tags: load-testing, thrift, performance-testing

I have to start performance/load testing of thrift apis. Wanted to know what tools/best practices available for good load test?
I am currently looking into Apache JMeter. Please let me know other options available and any information related to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter may suit you more than other tools. You can start study it with [Apache JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) or [JMeter Video tutorial](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/197560-jmeter-video-tutorial-writing-your-first-jmeter-s)